# Multiple services on the same port and url in development

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When deploying our services we have this structure:

```
*mainservice.com
mainservice.com/service2
mainservice.com/service3
etc*
```

For achieving this in IIS we have one website and multiple applications in sub virtual directories in this website. What I'm trying to do is recreating this behavior in development.

Comment: Use IIS on your developer machines.

Comment: I want to debbug in meanwhile. Copying pdbs is an option but it would be easier if it is possible to happen through VS debug process

Comment: VS debugs stuff in IIS just fine @IavorOrlyov.